# Mapstruct don't assign any value

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, netbeans, lombok, mapstruct

I use lombok, mapstruct and spring boot 2.6. My ide is intellij 2020.2

My mapper

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface UserMapper {

    User userInfoToUser(UserInfo userInfo);
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="user_id_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="user_id_seq",sequenceName="user_id_seq", allocationSize=1)
    Long id;

    @Email
    @Column(length = 254, unique = true)
    String username;

    @Column(length = 20)
    String password;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    RoleEnum role;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "int default 0")
    int failedAttempt;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "boolean default true")
    boolean accountNonLocked;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "boolean default false")
    boolean requirePasswordChange;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "boolean default true")
    boolean enabled;

}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserInfo {

    private Long id;

    @Email
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String username;

    @Size(min = 8)
    private String password;
}
```

Code generated is

```
@Component
public class UserMapperImpl implements UserMapper {

    @Override
    public User userInfoToUser(UserInfo userInfo) {
        if ( userInfo == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        User user = new User();

        return user;
    }
}
```

In my gradle file I have

```
implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.4.2.Final'
compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.4.2.Final'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
```

Code generated is not good, all set are missing.

same issue with netbeans

Comment: It seems that the `lombok-mapstruct-binding` annotation processor is missing.

Comment: don't change nothing, I think it's more a intellij issue

Comment: Edit: removed previous comment, because I misinterpreted your response. 
Did you refresh the configuration in your IDE after adding it?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Lombok 1.18.16 or newer you need to add lombok-mapstruct-binding in order to make Lombok and MapStruct work together